# jQuery Spinner - get value from spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-spinner

I am using  [jQuery Spinner](https://github.com/vsn4ik/jquery.spinner) and dont know how to get value from spinner to use in javascript code.

JS - in separate library i need to call value

```js
function calculate (){
    var result = 15 * HERE I NEED VALUE! ;
   
 }
```

```html
<div class="input-group spinner" data-trigger="spinner">
          <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="0" data-rule="quantity">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="spin-up" data-spin="up"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="spin-down" data-spin="down"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Something like this

```js
$("#spinner")
  .spinner('delay', 200) //delay in ms
  .spinner('changed', function(e, newVal, oldVal) {
    // trigger lazed, depend on delay option.
  })
  .spinner('changing', function(e, newVal, oldVal) {
    // trigger immediately
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vsn4ik/jquery.spinner/master/dist/js/jquery.spinner.min.js"></script>

<div data-trigger="spinner" id="spinner">
  <a href="javascript:;" data-spin="down">-</a>
  <input type="text" value="1" data-rule="quantity">
  <a href="javascript:;" data-spin="up">+</a>
</div>
```